# FPL Api authentication with JavaScript and Angular(HttpClient)

Tags: javascript, angular, api, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to auth with FPL api 
can anyone help me with the below, I could not find what is wrong

here is the authentication guide https://medium.com/@bram.vanherle1/fantasy-premier-league-api-authentication-guide-2f7aeb2382e4

I get this error

> status: 200
>
> statusText: "OK"
>
> url:
>   "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/"
>
> ok: false
>
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"
>
> message: "Http failure during parsing for
>   https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/"

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';




constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}



getData() {


    const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

    this.http
      .post(${proxy}https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/,
   {
      redirect_uri: 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/login',
      app: 'plfpl-web',
      login: 'my-email',
      password: 'may-pass'
    }
)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the URL you specified for your request, it will tell you what the problem is exactly :

> Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with